# Rails Forms and Custom Ajax Calls to a Different Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 Models, Channel, Tag and then Channel Tags, they have a has many through relationship which is set up as so:

**Channel Model**

```
has_many :tags, :through => :channel_tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :channel_tags, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Tag Model**

```
has_many :channel_tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :channels, :through => :channel_tags, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Channel Tags Model**

```
belongs_to :channel
belongs_to :tag
```

On my Edit Channel Form I have a text input for the user to enter a tag and then a custom js plugin that makes an ajax call to the database to check for existing tags that match the search, if no results are found, the user can add the search term as a new tag, classic functionality for any blogging platform. However I am having some problems with adding a new tag. I have the following JS to make a post:

```
var name = _ts.$input.val(),
    auth_token = $('input[name="authenticity_token"]').val();

$.post('/tags/?&authenticity_token=' + auth_token, { name : name }, function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

When I first did this, I was getting errors that it was an invalid authenticity_token, I am assuming this is because it is because the code is for an edit channel form and not a new tag form. I read a suggestion to add the following to the tag controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

That worked although I am not sure it is the best solution?

But now I am getting a 400 error saying:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in TagsController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: tag
```

I am pretty confident this is because of the following in my Tags Controller:

```
 def tag_params
    params.require(:tag).permit(:name,
                                :slug
    )
  end
```

I am however unsure how to work around it? Is there a special method for interacting with rails with custom JS? I have read the documentation around using the form_for with remote but that is not applicable to what I am trying to do.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Many thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should get your authenticity token from `meta` tag (from header), not from hidden input, because the token is always present in header. Then you should setup AJAX calls, so that `X-CSRF-Token` header will be sent with all your requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    var token = $('meta[name="csrftoken"]').attr('content');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
  }
});
```

Now you can keep original `protect_from_forgery` method. I don't think it's a good idea to use `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` here. You should then implement other authorization mechanism.

As to your parameters, based on the request:

```
$.post('/tags', { name : name }, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Params which `TagsController#create` receives, will be `{name: 'tag name'}`. So `params.require(:tag)` will surely be missing. You should use; `params.permit(:name)` instead. But, I think, it's better again, to follow Rails defaults and change your AJAX call instead:

```
$.post('/tags', { tag: { name : name } }, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: you are my hero!! that is exactly what I was looking for!! All makes perfect sense, i didnt feel the null_session approach was the best myself so really glad to not have to worry about that. Only very minor adjustment is the jquery selector for the csrftoken should be 'meta[name="csrf-token"]' with a hyphon. many thanks again!!

Comment: null_session is a good approach when you have other auth mechanism (OAuth for example) in your app.